# Calling getBoundingClientRect() on element returns object with zero values

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a simple ionic 5.31.1 / Angular 11.1.0 web app where I place a div (inner div) inside another div (outer div).
I want to access the position of the inner div relative to the outer div from the code. Calling `getBoundingClientRect()` to the inner div returns an object where `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, `x` and `y` are all `0`.

Here is the code

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { DomController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    private readonly platform: Platform,
    private readonly splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private readonly statusBar: StatusBar, 
    private readonly domCtrl: DomController
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  @ViewChild('box') 
  private box: ElementRef;


  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
  
  
  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    await this.domCtrl.read(() => {
      console.log(this.box.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()); // <-- returns { top: 0, bottom: 0, ... }
    });
  }
}
```

#### app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <div class="outer-box">
    <div #box class="inner-box"></div>
  </div>
</ion-app>
```

#### app.component.scss

```
.outer-box {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%; 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner-box {
  position: relative; 
  background: blue; 
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Angulars AfterContentChecked lifecycle since you are projecting your html to the  component

```
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    if (this.box) {
      await this.domCtrl.read(() => {
        console.log(this.box.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect());
      });
    }
  }
```

And just for a test try to add a setTimeout function inside the life cycle hook and only then getBoundingClientRect(), perhaps the element havent been fully rendered when you are checking it

Comment: when putting the code into the ngAfterContentChecked() hook this.box is undefined. When I replace the await part in ngAfterViewInit() with setTimeout(...) then getBoundingClientRect() returns the right bounds, but only when I set the timeout value to several seconds. This is unfortunately not acceptable in my case

Comment: A few seconds? Thats strange, obviously a timeout is not the solution just wanted to show that your method is correct and the problem lies with angular not fully rendering it yet. Perhpas there is something delaying the render of this component? I cannot be few seconds..

Comment: you could use RxJs and create an observable for that element and subscribe to it,  when the element changes you will receive an emit and could check its clientRect values, if not yet fully rendered then wait for the next emit